# Algebraic numbers - check if $3$ is prime in $G$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As given in the book by Pollard, Diamond, on Algebraic Numbers, there are proofs for Norm, as shown below in pg. 6,7,8,9 of the book.

[image]
[image]

Have below doubts:

1. I hope that on page 6, the books means by $H$ the set of algebraic integers that have the form $a + b\sqrt{-5}$.
2. On page 8, there is proof for proving the converse of (v) as false. The part (v) on page 7, is: If $N\alpha$ is prime in $J$, then $\alpha$ is prime in $G$.
   So, the converse is: If $\alpha$ is prime in $G$, then $N\alpha$ is prime in $J$.

The book states that : To see this it is enough to show that $3$ is prime in $G$(Gaussian integers), for $N3 = 3^2 = 9$.

I am unclear as to how the above statement is true. My understanding is that if a number (here, $3$), if expressible as a product of terms in the form $a +bi (a +b\sqrt{-1})$, then it is not a prime in $G$. Similar, can be said about $H$ too, i.e. the change is of : $a + b\sqrt{-5}$ from above.

So, the question is --- how can one check if $3$ is not a prime in $G$, just by saying that the norm (square of number) is $9$. Is the reason that the factors possible $(a+bi)(a-bi) \ne 9$, for any $a,b \in J$, as $a^2 + b^2 =9$ means no integer value can be given to $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $3 = \alpha \beta$, then $9=N(3)=N(\alpha)N(\beta)$. Therefore,  $N(\alpha)=1,3,9$. Can we have $N(\alpha)=3$ ?

Solution:

> No, we cannot have $N(\alpha)=3$ because $a^2 + b^2 =3$ has no solution $a,b \in \mathbb Z$. Therefore, $N(\alpha)=1$ or $9$. Now, $N(\alpha)=1$ iff $\alpha \in \{\pm 1, \pm i\}$. And $N(\alpha)=9$ iff $N(\beta)=1$. So, $3 = \alpha \beta$ implies $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a unit, and so $3$ is irreducible in $G$.

Comment: But, why your question in hint was : Can we have $N(\alpha) = 3$. I feel it should have been $N(\alpha) = 9$. Else, please tell me why I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.